# Get new emails with microsoft graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get only new emails with microsoft graph.
Iam doing this by checking date like

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=receivedDateTime+gt+2016-06-06T08:08:08Z
```

Is there any possibility to build query to get new messages but base on id instead of receivedDateTime? Something like: get messeges until you find id=....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the delta query solution is pretty good (as suggested in a different answer).  However, for my purposes, there were two major drawbacks: 1) it's in preview (beta) right now, so it makes it less than ideal for production code and 2) it doesn't seem to support the monitoring of *all* messages, just those in a particular folder.

I actually prefer the solution you're working with.  The timestamp in the header of the response can be used to reset the time field in you query, so that if you have "receivedDateTime gt 12:00:00" and get back the server time of 12:01:00 for your request, you can use "receivedDateTime gt 12:01:00" next time.

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you're looking for is specifically what the new [Delta query](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_messages) is designed to support. Deltas allow you to retrieve changes to a given folder (i.e. Inbox) since you last polled that folder. Message IDs not static or consecutive so they're not a suitable property for determining new vs. old messages.

Comment: That page is a 404 and it was not archived on https://web.archive.org . Was that query method adopted? Where is the documentation now?

Comment: I seem to have found the new link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http